# Font display in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, character-encoding, localization

I have a java application that originally runs in Windows, and the UI doesn't have any problem in displaying Chinese and Japanese. But now on Linux (Fedora), in a JPanel, I can't type Chinese or Japanese.

Then, I tried JTextPane.setFont(...) for a Chinese font, it displays correctly.  My question is, why don't I have to set font explicitly for Chinese and Japanese on Windows, but have to do that on Linux?

Comment: I'd start by checking the locale setting on each platform.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Should I set that in java code or on Fedora system? Thanks.